# Discarding data in the result set.Transact SQL/SQL Server Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

**Query:**
select Name , date_time, Asset value1, Asset value2 from Employee where name in (Ben,Joe).

**Output :**

```
Name    date_time     Asset value1  Asset value2
Ben   9/30/2014 0:00    558.12        2258.12
Ben   10/1/2014 0:00    558.96        2258.96
Ben   10/2/2014 0:00    558.07        2258.07
Ben   10/3/2014 0:00    558.22        2258.22
Ben   10/4/2014 0:00    558.37        2258.37
Joe   9/30/2014 0:00    551.33        2151.33
Joe   10/1/2014 0:00    551.32        2151.32
Joe   10/2/2014 0:00    551.06        2151.06
Joe   10/3/2014 0:00    551.89        2151.89
Joe   10/4/2014 0:00    551.24        2151.24
Joe   10/5/2014 0:00    551.08        2151.08
```

How can I achieve the below condition ?
If 'Ben' has 9/30/2014 date_time and the other one does not, then discard the data.

Here in the above output 'Joe' has date_time 10/5/2014 0:00 whereas 'Ben' doesn't. How can I exclude that row having date_time 10/5/2014 0:00.
Could someone help me to modify the present query or write a new one for the same.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are trying to do here.

Answer (score 2):

```
select disinct E1.Name , E1.date_time
from Employee E1
join Employee E2 
  on E1.Name = 'Ben' 
 and E2.Name = 'Joe' 
 and E1.date_time = E2.date_time
UNION 
select disinct E1.Name , E1.date_time
from Employee E1
join Employee E2
  on E2.Name = 'Ben' 
 and E1.Name = 'Joe' 
 and E1.date_time = E2.date_time
```